# generate url in specific language with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, routes, attributerouting

Working with attribute routing for mvc4 and very happy with it.

I have a question though, my site supports 2 languages and I have localized all my url's. The supported languages are french and english.

When the site is in english, I would like to show a link to switch to french, and ve se versa.

With attribute routing, is there way to generate a url for a specific culture/language? Currently when the site is in english, all the url's are localized in English. I am wondering if it would be possible to generate this one link in French.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you meant when you wrote "generate a url", since AttributeRouting does not generate urls--it matches them. Would you please include a code sample?

Answer (score -2):

While this guide was written for MVC 2, I think it'll help..

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

> Now we'll create simple user control with supported culture hyper
>   links. Add new partial view to Views\Shared folder
>   CultureChooserUserControl.ascx and paste following
>
> ```
> <%= Html.ActionLink("English", "ChangeCulture", "Account",  
>      new { lang = "en", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)%>
> <%= Html.ActionLink("Русский", "ChangeCulture", "Account",  
>      new { lang = "ru", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl }, null)%>
> ```
>
> We just now created two hyper links, first one for English and second
>   one for Russian languages. And now its time to place this culture
>   chooser user control to Site.Master master page. I'll add this to
>    corresponding to login functionality just as an example.

I am not an expert on localization and may be leading you down the wrong path

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no, this is not what I required. My question is regarding attribute routing and how it could generate a localized url for a specific culture.